# Perform update query after delete in django cbv

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to update other table after successful delete of of data. Below is my
`views.py`

```
class AttendeeDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Attendee
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        id = self.kwargs['id']  # get value of enr
        Payment.objects.filter(pk=id).update(registered=0)
```

In my `urls.py`

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', AttendeeDeleteView.as_view(template_name="includes/attendee_delete.html"), name='attendee_delete',),
```

My Current code successfully delete the item but failed to update the other table.

my model

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    payee = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    ticketNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ticketType = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=TICKET_CHOICES, default='paid')
    date = models.DateField('Date Paid (MM/DD/YYYY)', max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=200 ,blank=True, null=True)
    registered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.payee



class Attendee(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    payment = models.OneToOneField(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=DEPT_CHOICES, default='')
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

UPDATE 1:

I followed [this](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/) came up with

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs['pk']  # get value of enr
        context = Payment.objects.filter(pk=id).update(registered=0)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

but it returned `context must be a dict rather than int.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `def get_form_kwargs(self):` doesn't executed, because it used for `FormMixin`. But, you can also handle it inside `get()` function.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    attendee = self.get_object()
    Payment.objects.filter(pk=attendee.payment.pk).update(registered=0)

    context = self.get_context_data(object=attendee)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

See this https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/ for more..

---

**Edit:**

This solution below if still getting a problem when using `get()` method.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
....


def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Calls the delete() method on the fetched object and then
    redirects to the success URL.
    """
    self.object = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()

    Payment.objects.filter(pk=self.object.payment.pk).update(registered=0)

    self.object.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. I updated my question above to apply my suggestion but I got a response `context must be a dict rather than int.`

Comment: It returned an error inside `kswargs['id']`, I assume it must be `pk` so I change it and it returned `The view attendee.views.AttendeeDeleteView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: it says `KeyError at /alumni/delete/16`
`'id'`,

Comment: just change `kwargs['id']` to `kwargs['pk']`, see my update.. this because your urls.py used `pk` for it.

Comment: I used `id = kwargs['pk']` instead of `id = kwargs['id']` . It deletes the item but no update happened.

Comment: if you see with correctly, this `pk` is used for model `Attendee` and not for `Payment` model. of course it different...

Comment: let me see your models of `Attendee` and `Payment` to check the foreignkey field..

Comment: I included it in my question

Comment: it returned `'AttendeeDeleteView' object has no attribute 'object'`

Comment: by changing this line
`a = Attendee.objects.get(pk=pk)
Payment.objects.filter(pk=a.payment.pk).update(registered=0)` works for me. Thank you thank you.

Comment: perhaps can be handle insie the `delete` function.. https://pastebin.com/6QZLakij

Comment: `from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect` missed import